# Retrying failed attempts with NodeJS/ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js

Foreword: I am newer to Javascript after coming from a C++ background.

I am writing a NodeJS app using a public npm library to request a few sets of data. The data source rate limits requests, and in a few extreme cases these rate limits are hit. When these limits are hit, the API will only return "Rate Limit Exceeded" for a few seconds before processing more requests.

When I receive the data, I try to parse it using `.map()`. However, when the rate limit exceeds, the whole app comes crashing down because `map()` is only available for arrays, and the "Rate Limit Exceeded" message is just a simple object.

```
if (message.message === 'Rate limit exceeded') { //This check doesn't work btw
    console.log('There was a problem parsing data from the server: ' + err);
    return;
    }

    var items = data.map(item => ({
        time: new Date(item[0] * 1000),
        low: item[1],
        high: item[2],
        open: item[3],
        close: item[4],
        volume: Number(item[5])
    }));

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        dataStore.push(items[i]);
```

I want to approach this by detecting the "Rate Limit Exceeded" message, waiting a few seconds, and then retrying.

From my current understanding, `setTimeout()` would be a good candidate for this, but I do not understand how to get it to work recursively. Essentially, I would like it to re-request data every five seconds until the data is correctly processed.

TL;DR: I want a function to recursively call itself with `setTimeout()` until it properly receives data; or if there is a better way to achieve this, I am all ears.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is use `setInterval()` and keep on checking every n seconds. Once you get the data, you can exit out the `setInterval()` using `clearInterval()`.

Note that am using jQuery here in this context as am not sure if you are using any particular NPM package to request the data.

```js
let retryAfter = 10000; //10 seconds

setInterval(function fetchData() {
  $.get('//api.jsonbin.io/b/5a3823a38aaf400a97709c43', (data) => {
  
    // Keep on retrying
    console.log(data);

    // If you get the data, just exit the setInterval
    if(data) {
      clearInterval(fetchData);
    }
  });
}(), retryAfter); 

//() brackets here is to execute the function without the first 10 sec delay
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As of now, in this example, my `setInterval()` will run just once as it gets the data at first. But in your example, it will run until you receive the data.

Also, I can't suggest how you are supposed to compare the error message of yours as am not sure the API which is returning you the error message is in the form of a JSON or plain text. It depends on how you can compare the error message based on the response data type.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do
if(Array.isArray(data) === false) return;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray